# Plugin child Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I want to add the next line to one of files of woocommerce in concrete: wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\archive-product.php

```html
<div class="breadcrumps-header"><?php if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) ) {yoast_breadcrumb();} ?></div>
```

But in the next update of Woocommerce I'll loose the modification. How can I do it to add like plugin chlid?

Comment: Check if the template in question has any hooks in that region that could be used to insert the content from the outside; if not, you can declare “woocommerce support” within your own theme, and overwrite specific WC template files from there afterwards.

Comment: Are you using child theme?

Comment: First of all, I would recommend to find a hook for the breadcrump first. If there is, you might be able to adding your code using the hook. The php file should be place in your child theme folder or new plugin folder to prevent deleting by update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at that file (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/v2.2.3/templates/archive-product.php), you'll see a number of different actions you can use depending on where you want that content inserted.

For example, near the top there's this:

```
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
```

The comment shows that woocommerce's own breadcrumbs are hooked to this action with a priority of 20.

If you wanted your code to appear after this, you should be able to add something like the following to your theme's `functions.php` (or somewhere else):

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', function() { ?>
<div class="breadcrumps-header">
    <?php if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) ) {yoast_breadcrumb();} ?>
</div>
<?php });
```

`25` is the priority, ensuring your code will execute after woocommerce's `woocommerce_breadcrumb` function.

There are lots of other `do_action`s in that script, so choose the one closest to where you want your code and you should get what you need with a little experimentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! I installed "code snippets plugin" and I have added your code and it worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to hear it was what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you create folder in your theme and name it `woocommerce` and copy all files from `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\` to your `wp-content\themes\yourthemename\woocommerce\` you can place changes to this file and after next WooCommerce update it will not lost, only it will show you that you use old version of template if they placed changes to the same original file and you will have to manually merge them. And create child theme first if it's not your own theme, don't place woocommerce folder to original theme.

And, better to put `div` inside `if`, because you don't want to show empty div if this function doesn't exist, right?

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'yoast_breadcrumb' ) ) { ?>
<div class="breadcrumps-header"><?php yoast_breadcrumb(); ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi!! Thanks for your answer. I tested your way but I don't like, anyway It's very easy to do. Thanks a lot